# protractor how do you run a single test case?

Tags: protractor

I'm using protractor 1.8.0 and jasmine 2.1.3 but
I can't run a single test when I use ddescribe and then iit. I get:

`Message: ReferenceError: iit is not defined`

I have a lot of test cases and want to just run 1 for debugging purposes. Is there a way to do this?

Do I need to $npm install jasmine-focused or is it already part of jasmine 2.1.3?

@Aaron I went ahead and uninstalled and reinstall. Ran the test and got the same error. Here is the output after install.

```
/usr/local/bin/protractor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
/usr/local/bin/webdriver-manager -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
protractor@1.8.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor
├── jasminewd@1.1.0
├── jasminewd2@0.0.2
├── saucelabs@0.1.1
├── html-entities@1.1.2
├── q@1.0.0
├── minijasminenode@1.1.1
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0
├── source-map-support@0.2.9 (source-map@0.1.32)
├── lodash@2.4.1
├── request@2.36.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.3, http-signature@0.10.1, form-data@0.1.4, tough-cookie@0.12.1, hawk@1.0.0)
├── jasmine@2.1.1 (jasmine-core@2.1.3)
└── selenium-webdriver@2.44.0 (tmp@0.0.24, xml2js@0.4.4)
```

Comment: hello did you tried doing starting your selenium server on console by typing: webdriver-manager start?

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for that as of 2.1 is `fdescribe` and `fit`. [Source](http://pivotallabs.com/new-key-features-jasmine-2-1/)

```
describe('a test', function() {
    it('spec 1', function() {
        console.log('1');
    });

    it('spec 2', function() {
        console.log('2');
    });

    it('spec 3', function() {
        console.log('3');
    });
});
```

This will print:

```
1
.2
.3
.
```

Meanwhile:

```
fdescribe('a test', function() {
    it('spec 1', function() {
        console.log('1');
    });

    fit('spec 2', function() {
        console.log('2');
    });

    it('spec 3', function() {
       console.log('3');
    });
});
```

Will print:

```
2
.
```

Comment: its not working for me. i have: `fdescribe('page', function(){ it(); fit(); it(); });` when I run I get launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started


No specs found
Finished in 0.002 seconds

Comment: I can get xit to work but not fdescribe and fit. Do we have a possible bug?

Comment: @awaken I would double check your configurations and versions, I just tested fdescribe and fit and it worked for me. Are you giving the its and fits functions to run?

Comment: I only have one spec file I'm referring to. Maybe it's wrong. Is this correct? `specs: ['./tests/homepage/se123_spec.js']` am I missing something? Your 2nd example is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @awaken since I can't see your file structure I can't really speak to whether or not that's the right filepath, but based on the error you're getting I would say it's an architecture issue rather than a code issue.

Comment: so I ran the test with just fdescribe and it runs all it()s. when I modify just 1 it() to fit(), then the error appears.

Comment: I noticed similar behaviour when I run tests against selenium hub. Although it runs all of my tests, not only the selected one.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Aaron for leading me to this. I finally figured out the answer. I had to comment out my declaration of  jasmine-reporters in my config file:

`/*var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        filePrefix: 'verifi_portal_tests_xmloutput',
        savePath: './test_results_report'
    }));*/`

It works after I do this. The problem now is how do I include jasmine-reporters and still make fdescribe and fit work.

UPDATE: the correct answer is to update jasmine-reporters from 2.0.4 to 2.0.5. I did this and it fixed the problem.